# C++: Method into another method

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++, so please don't be harsh on me.

This is my header, `cblock.hpp`:

```
#ifndef CBLOCK_H
#define CBLOCK_H
#include "ctime.hpp"
#include <iostream>

class CBlock
{
 public:
   CBlock();
   CBlock(short m_BlockNr,CTime m_Begin);

   short getBlockNr();
   void print() const;
   void getEnd();
   
   ~CBlock(){};

 private:
   short BlockNr = 1;
   CTime Begin;


};

#endif
```

And this is `cblock.cpp`:

```
#include "cblock.hpp"
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

CBlock::CBlock(short m_BlockNr, CTime m_Begin)
{
  BlockNr = m_BlockNr;
  Begin = m_Begin;
}

short CBlock::getBlockNr()
{
  return BlockNr;
}

void CBlock::getEnd() //Adding 90 Minutes to the current time
{
  int STD = (Begin.Minute + 30) / 60;
  Begin.Minute = (Begin.Minute + 30) % 60;
  Begin.Hour = Begin.Hour + 1 + STD;
}

void CBlock::print() const
{
  //Current time
  cout << setfill('0') << setw(2) << Begin.Hour << ":" << setw(2) << Begin.Minute << " – "; 
 
  getEnd();  //I know this is not possible but I guess you understood what I'm trying to do here.

  //After 90 Minutes 
  cout << setfill('0') << setw(2) << Begin.Hour << ":" << setw(2) << Begin.Minute << endl; 
 
}
```

I want the `getEnd()` method to change the `Begin.Hour` and `Begin.Minute`, but I don't know how I can call a method in another method.

Comment: "_I guess you understood what I'm trying to do here_" - No I don't, and the call to `getEnd()` seems legit. What error do you get? Edit: Aha, it's `const`. You will have to decide if you think it's reasonable for a `print` method to change the object it's printing out. If you think that's reasonable, remove `const` from `print()`.

Comment: A `class` or `struct` method is allowed to call methods of the class, base class methods and free standing functions.

Comment: A `const` member function can't call a non-`const` member function (without casting away the `const` on `*this`).

Comment: Yet more answers in the comments section I see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It certainly is possible!

The trouble is that your `print()` function is `const`, which means it can only access its class in a `const` way.

`getEnd()` is *not* `const`, so `print()` can't call it.

It's a bit weird for something called "get" to actually *set*; perhaps you'd like to return a fresh value from that function instead? You could call it `calculateEnd()`. You can always assign it later.

But if you do want these operations in `print()` to modify its class, then it cannot be marked `const`, because `const` means it cannot modify its class.

Comment: You're right . Yea it's weird setting a value with a get method . The problem is that I couldn't find a solution to implement an idea with the real **get**